# How to ship XulRunner with SWT app?

Tags: java, browser, swt, mozilla, xulrunner

I need to ship a specific version (1.8.1.3) of XulRunner with my SWT app. My current plan is to detect the current platform and download XulRunner to the app data path of that platform. That's no problem, but to what file in that am I supposed to set the XulRunnerPath property to?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "_but to what file in that_"?

Comment: I downloaded three XulRunner 1.8.1.3 folders from the Mozilla repo, one for each platform, which contains the .dll's and .jar's. I need to know which one SWT needs to run a "new Browser(shell, SWT.MOZILLA);" I tried taking a guess, and an exception stated that I needed a "swt-xulrunner-win32.dll" from "Users\<NAME>\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\". If I wanted to download XulRunner on first run, what would I download, and what string would I use to set the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you include it in build.properties. I would suggest you to create a fragment for the SWT like how SWT does it for each platform. You need to set System property `org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath` to the dll. Please refer to

```
org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla
static void LoadLibraries () {---}
```

Fragment:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_a_plug-in_fragment%3F

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to mention that I'm new to Java altogether. What is a fragment? Which dll am I supposed to set the XulRunnerPath to? Lastly, what jar is org.swt.browser.Mozilla in, because it's not in the swt.jar.

Comment: org.swt.browser.Mozilla is a class in SWT API.  It should be there org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.10.jar fragment if you are using eclipse win 32 x86machine.

Comment: Ah, it does show it, but it is not visible. Regardless, I just found out you can can just download XulRunner and register it in the system, and I only need it in case a Linux user doesn't have it. So thanks for your help anyway.